# see if textarea value exists in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert, compare

I have a conundrum.  I have a simple form.  A dynamic select list that is pulling technician names from a database and a textarea.   The form is intended for me to paste zipcodes (in this format: 12345,12346,12347,etc) and for them to be inserted into a table one by one along with the tech's id.  This works great!  However, just any zip won't do - as I have to have a license to work in it.

To get around that annoying issue, I created a table that has a list of zip codes I do service.  SO, I have a recordset of those zip codes, I'm inserting them into an array, and then checking to see if value from textarea exist in that array before it is inserted.  Except, it isn't working.  The array printed fine - so that works.  The insert stuff works fine - as it did before I added the in_array stuff.  Together - they're like my girlfriend and me.  It just doesn't freaking work together.

Here is my code:

```
//This is my recordset and where I'm putting it into an array
mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT zip_code FROM zip_code";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
$results = array();
do {
  $results[] = $row_Recordset1;
} while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1));
//DONE ARRAY
//Now I'm taking zipcodes pasted in textarea so they can be inserted one at a time
$zipcodes = explode(",", $_POST['textarea']);
$countZips = (count($zipcodes));
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
foreach($zipcodes as $key=>$value)
{

while ($countZips >= 1) {
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
//DONE textarea
    //If statement to see if value exists in array
        if (in_array($value, $results)){
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO zip_zip (zip_code, tech_id) VALUES (%s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($value, "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['select'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
    $countZips--;
} else {
    $countZips--;
}
//Done value exists
//Now moving to next page when done
} 
    $insertGoTo = "index.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
}

//END
```

Does anyone know what in the world the problem is?   Also - if someone edits this and makes the code formatting pretty - how do you do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change following line

$results[] = $row_Recordset1;

to below line
$results[] = $row_Recordset1['zip_code'];

In your code, while fetching record from DB, you are assigning each row into your $result array, thats why when you are going to check $value in your $result array giving you false result, bcoz your $result array has following structure as per your above mentioned code

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [zip_code] => 12312331
        )
)

and you require following array structure for in_array()

Array
(
    [0] => 12312331
)

Comment: That works perfectly if there is just a single zip code put into the text field.  If there are more than one such as 43213,99999   it doesn't do anything.  Shouldn't it be checking each zip code as it is being inserted in the loop?

Comment: That might work actually.  I just realized without the addition of the array, it is repeatedly inserting the same zip code the number of times that there are zip codes in the textarea.  So my loop on inserting the information is wrong to begin with.